# One process writing while the other one reads the shared memory

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, shared-memory

I have 2 programs (processes). One process writes to shared memory while the other reads it. So, my approach was like this:
Initially, value of shared memory is 0. So, process 1 writes only when value is 0. Now process 1 has written some other value to shm and "waits" till value becomes 0. Process 2 reads the shm and writes 0 to it. By wait, I mean in while(1) loop.

My question is if this approach fine or can I do better with some other approach in terms of CPU usage and memory usage?

Comment: We might need to know more about the purpose, but i would suggest to read up on `unix sockets` and `message queues`. Both of these are inter process communication (IPC) mechanisms, like shared memory.

Comment: A ` while(1)` never ends.

Comment: I am breaking from it when condition satisfies

Comment: [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) is probably not what you want here. You probably should use some synchronization mecanism provided by your OS.

Comment: I have used synchronization. But my problem is 1st process cannot write until 2nd has read it. Only after 2nd process has read will the 1st process write....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned problem known as Process Synchronization problem and given logic is nothing but Busy Waiting approach of the problem which is very primary solution.

Read [Producer-Consumer Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) which is similiar to given problem.

There are some better solutions to this than Busy Waiting like:

Spinlock, Semaphore etc.

You can get basic knowledge of all of this from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science))

Hope it will help!!

Comment: If I write in one process and read in another process at the same time, I can get dirty data? On windows if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fine but the problem occurs when both the process write to a shared memory block.
At that time you could use a semaphore to synchronize the two process allowing one at a time to write to shared resource/memory block.
You can find regarding Semaphores Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)